# Thunderbird equivalent of Claws Mail actions

Tags: thunderbird

I've used [Claws Mail](https://www.claws-mail.org) for over a decade and have been a very happy user. Unfortunately though the lack of HTML mail composing has become too much of a handicap, since even normal mails get broken up oddly as a result of the [RFC 822 line length restriction](https://mailformat.dan.info/body/linelength.html).

I'd like to switch to Thunderbird. But Claws has a feature I simply can't do without - I can set up an "Action", which basically means that a message can be piped to an external script.  Since I can then assign a keyboard shortcut to that Action, this means I can process my mails into my todo.txt etc. with just a keystroke.

Does Thunderbird have similar functionality?  I am only able to find answers that [seem to allow for only scripting within Thunderbird](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3096187/thunderbird-scripting) or a [plugin that is really really old](https://code.google.com/archive/p/tbscript-plugin/).

Comment: Surely Claws has support for Quoted-Printable or Base64 transfer encoding? The line length restrictions apply to the final (encoded) source, and most messages aren't sent raw as typed – they're usually sent QP-encoded to allow for lines as long as you need.

Comment: I don't think it does. At least I've never found an option for this, and the compose window insists on breaking lines as per the line length. The result is not usually a complete mess, but it is inelegant, especially when no one else's emails follow that restriction.

Comment: The compose window folds lines to ~80 columns by tradition, as many email apps do, and that has nothing to do with the RFC822 limit. If you disable auto-wrapping in _Edit_, Claws is supposed to allow any length and simply encode the body in QP or B64 before sending. Which... it actually does, but _only_ if the message contains some non-ASCII characters. The functionality _is_ there (you can even select QP through Preferences/Send), but it is buggy; it ought to automatically do this for overlong lines as well. As a workaround I'd just put some Unicode in my signature.

Comment: That's brilliant, thank you! I can't believe that in all these years I never found this option or strategy. I still would like HTML mail composing but this addresses my biggest bugbear. I'm leaving the question here though since it may be of interest to others in any case.